# Apache KafkaMetric value method deprecated, how to use metricValue instead?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

so I have created a function to get metrics from Kafka topic

```
    public <T extends KafkaTemplate> Double getMetricValue(String key, T kafkaTemplate) {
    for (final Object set : kafkaTemplate.metrics().entrySet()) {
        Map.Entry map = (Map.Entry) set;
        MetricName metricName = (MetricName) map.getKey();
        KafkaMetric kafkaMetric = (KafkaMetric) map.getValue();

        if (metricName.name().equals(key)) {
            return kafkaMetric.value();
        }
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

It is going to be used for example: `Utils.getMetricValue("buffer-available-bytes", kafkaTemplate);`

Problem is that now as per docs: https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/common/Metric.html
value method is deprecated! it was returning a Double.

Now we need to use metricValue which returns Object, but there is no documentation how to use it, and I could not find any examples by googling either.

So any idea how to adapt the above function best to use metricValue instead? I would like to get rid of the deprecation warning, and future proof while doing it.

This is another prime example of what I hate about Java.. no usage examples in documentation is the norm for it :(

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the source code. `metricValue()` can return two different values.

1. It returns Double - Exactly as `value()`.
2. It returns type T - Which I assume depends on your implementation of Kafka.

I expect Double will be returned in your case due to your input `buffer-available-bytes`.

There is a lot of documentation about Java... Just not in this particular case. I think the lack of documentation is due to the combination of Kafka is mostly used in enterprises and this change is relative new.

I encourage you to look into the source code and figure out the default types used in `org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics`.

Just a last note. This is not Spring-Kafka specific but related to Apache-Kafka.